# Associating multiple teams with multiple headers/values:

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want you to take a look at this site:

http://www.nhl.com/ice/teamstats.htm

Now, I have my code here. This only prints out all the headers on the top of the table:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = urlopen("http://www.nhl.com/ice/teamstats.htm")

content = url.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

results = {}

for table in soup.find_all('table', class_='data stats'):
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        name = None
        for cell in row.find_all('th'):
            link = cell.find('a')
            if link:
                name = cell.a.string
                print (name)
```

Assuringly, this stuff is more complicated. I was able, with a lot of help and relearning of some forgotten Python classes, able to do this association of teams and scores over at this website: http://sports.yahoo.com/nhl/scoreboard?d=2013-04-01

However, the former webpage (first one) has multiple headers associated with their values.

What I just ask is for the gist of some of it, so that I may further accomplish the rest without problems (or maybe a few, who knows). In a sense, this is what I wish to accomplish:

```
Team X: GP: 30. W: 16. L: 4, etc.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only handle `th`. should also handle `td`.

Try following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

u = urlopen("http://www.nhl.com/ice/teamstats.htm")
soup = BeautifulSoup(u)
u.close()

for table in soup.find_all('table', class_='data stats'):
    row = table.find('tr')
    header = []
    for cell in row.find_all('th')[1:]:
        name = cell.string.strip()
        header.append(name)
    for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        for name, cell in zip(header, row.find_all('td')[1:]):
            value = cell.string.strip()
            print('{}: {}'.format(name, value), end=', ')
        print()
```

Comment: Good answer.

Out of curiosity, what does the zip do? Also, the [1:]. The rest is clear. @falsetru

Comment: @NathanielElder, `xs[1:]` return copy of the `xs` without the first element.

Comment: @NathanielElder, `zip(a, b)` combine each elements of `a` and `b`.  For example `zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])` yields `[(1,4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]`. On Python 3.x, yields iterator instead of list.